# Install plugin in Javascript for beginner

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, plugins

I know HTML and CSS good, but I never learn Javascript, and now, I found an interesting plugin for my website. But I don't know how I have to put it in the website.


So, is there anyone who can help me how to install the [plugin](https://github.com/qiqiboy/pageSwitch)

And [all my files from my website](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17uF1oKC1P1znEUCq9RUCo8SaPfBQwr6P)

Thank very much for your time!

Comment: to use this it looks like you're gonna need to learn both Mandarin and JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you don't use module of node, you have to download the file `https://github.com/qiqiboy/pageSwitch/blob/master/src/pageSwitch.js` then import it into your html `<script src="pageSwitch.js"></script>`.

Maybe it needs other plugins , I can't understand from your page, it's not in eng, so maybe : TouchSlider.js or tween.js for animations.

Then on the plugin page you can learn how yo use this [plugin](https://github.com/qiqiboy/pageSwitch) . Then import your css : `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">` and your image in html tag `<img src="...">`.

Put all them in the same folder.

Comment: If you have other problem ask here.